# How to get the contents of ckeditor on change?

Tags: javascript, plugins, ckeditor

I have the following code for detecting changes on the ckeditor surface.

```
CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].on("instanceReady", function(){                    
this.document.on("keyup", function(){
console.log("sth changed");
});
});
```

I would like to get the contents of editor on change for counting the words in it. How can I reach it using `CKEDITOR.instances`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **only correct** way to retrieve contents of the editor is:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.yourInstanceName.getData();
```

You can also try `this.on( 'key', function() { ... } );` because editor fires `key` events.

Additionally I recommend you [the ticket](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9794) regarding `onchange` event and monitoring changes in the editor.

And the last but not least: [The `wordcount` plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/wordcount) which has already been implemented and does your job ;)

Answer (score 4):

For version 5 you use `editor.model.document.on('change:data', ...)`.

So much like:

```
let someContent = '';

ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector('#editor')).then(editor => {
  editor.model.document.on('change:data', () => {
    someContent = editor.getData()
  })
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('error loading ckeditor', err);
})
```

Read the docs: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/basic-api.html#listening-to-changes

Answer (score 1):

There is an "onChange" plugin from @AlfonsoML in the plugins list:
[onChange](http://ckeditor.com/addon/onchange)

It covers a lot more than just "keyUp". You can read more on his blog, where he describes different events that are captured:
[onChange event for CKEditor](http://alfonsoml.blogspot.com/2011/03/onchange-event-for-ckeditor.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    CKEDITOR.instances["CKEditor"].on('change', function() { 
        console.log(this.getData());
    });
```

Comment: Hi confile, this answer showed up in the review feed, please consider adding a brief description as to how this resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<script>   
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
    CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on("change", function() {
        $("#content-val").html(this.getData())//show content inside #content-val div
    });
</script>
```